# finding the number of optional combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A 6 digits number built from 2,3,9.
1. how many numbers are divided by 2?
2. how many numbers are divided by 3?
3. how many numbers are divided by 6?

my Ans:
1. 3^4  (3*3*3*3*3*(1/3)) bc the last number must be 2
2. 481

I dont know how to solve the third Q, and not sure if 1, 2 are correct

Comment: The first one is $3^5$, because there is $6$ places to fill with $3$ numbers and the last one should be $2$.

Comment: How did you get the answers you say?

Comment: why?
its 3*3*3*3*3*(1/3) bc the last number must be 2

Comment: @opeer the last number must be a 2, sure, but you have 3 choices for each of the other 5, and order matters, where are you getting the 1/3 from?

Comment: @TimSeguine OK I got my mistake

Comment: @opeer you are counting combinations, not probabilities - there is $1$ way to choose $2$ from $2,3,9$.

Comment: Hi @opeer. You might find this [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

A number is divisible by $2$ precisely if its last digit is even.  In this case, that means that your last digit must be $2$.  So, the number of numbers that are divisible by $2$ is precisely the number in which the last digit is $2$, which is $3^5$. (You can choose any number for the other five positions.)

A number is divisible by $3$ precisely if its digits add up to a multiple of $3$.  Digits of $3$ or $9$ automatically do this; so, you only have to work about how many times $2$ appears.  In particular, it must appear either $0$, $3$, or $6$ times. By this reasoning, the answer to the second is
$$
\underbrace{1}_{\text{only $2$'s}}+\underbrace{\tbinom{6}{3}2^3}_{\text{three $2$'s}}+\underbrace{2^6}_{\text{no $2$'s}}=225.
$$
Why?  There's only one string consisting entirely of $2$'s; if there are to be three $2$'s, you can choose which positions are $2$ in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways, then put either $3$ or $9$ in each of the other three positions; and if there are no $2$'s, then each of six positions can be either $3$ or $9$.

I'm not going to answer the last one; but, can you see how to combine the condition we got for (1) with the condition we got for (2)?

Comment: I get 81 combinations divide by 6

Comment: There are 81 numbers divisible by 6, yes.